# Unable to change fan speed on Acer laptop

Tags: windows, laptop, drivers, speedfan

My laptop is Acer Swift SFX14-41G, which can use combination `Fn+F` to change fan speed. But after I reinstall Windows 10 from Microsoft (not use `reset this PC`) I am unable to change the fan speed.

So how can I get back this function and get back some useful function like that from Acer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go to the Acer.com website. Go to support, chose your model number. One of the downloads probably provides that functionality.

Comment: @Gantendo yes, I have tried to do that but I don't see any driver relate to fan speed.  How can I know what driver I should choose?